# How to call a CUDA file from a C++ header file?

Tags: cuda

I know the method of calling the .cu files from .c files. But now I want to call the .cu files from a C header file.  Is it possible to do it ? If so how should I make the settings of my project ? please help.....

Comment: c++ or c? mismatch between your title and content. what do you mean by calling xxx file from xxx file? usually we write some {.c/.cpp/.cu} code which may call functions declared in {.h/.hpp} and defined in {.c/.cpp/.cu}. which one is your case?

Comment: sry it is c++ file I have a function that should be run on the device part and it is located in say file1.cu  Now I have a c++ header file say file2.h  I need to know how to call the function that is situated in file1.cu from file2.h

Comment: You may want to re write you Q so more people will understand your meaning. In c/c++ you can only call functions that have been declared before the calling point. In your case you could either declare the function you want to call in file2.h or creat a file1.h containing declarations of functions in file1.cu and include it at the head of file2.h

Comment: This question makes no sense. Header files don't contain code, they contain declarations of types, templates and functions. Definitions, template instantiations, etc are put *once* somewhere in a source file which is compiled to emit executable code. It isn't at all clear what you are trying to ask about.....

Comment: Header files can contain function bodies. You just risk multiple definition errors if they arent inlined.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a worked example:

file1.h:

```
int hello();
```

file2.h:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "file1.h"

int myfunc(){
  hello();
  return 0;
}
```

file1.cu:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "file1.h"

__global__ void mykernel(){
  printf("Hello from mykernel\n");
}

int hello(){

  mykernel<<<1,1>>>();
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  return 0;
}
```

file2.cpp:

```
#include "file2.h"

int main(){
  myfunc();
  return 0;
}
```

build and test:

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_20 -c file1.cu
$ g++ -c file2.cpp
$ g++ -o test file1.o file2.o -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcudart
$ ./test
Hello from mykernel
$
```

Assuming you are intending to include your `file2.h` into a cpp file, you cannot call a cuda kernel directly from that header and use it in a cpp file.  You must put a wrapper around the cuda kernel, and call the wrapper, as I have indicated.  This is because your cpp file will get compiled by the host compiler, which doesn't know anything about cuda syntax (e.g. `mykernel<<<1,1>>>();`)

Also, as indicated in the comments, it may make more sense to reserve the header file `file2.h` just for needed prototypes, and put the actual function definition of `myfunc` into a cpp file somewhere.

Comment: For me, ` g++ -o test file1.o file2.o -L/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64 -lcudart` gives error. The test file is just coming and vanishing at the same time.
_/home/anaconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: file1.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.bss' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/home/anaconda3/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.2.0/../../../../x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status_